# wrong robot orientation at the goal

Tags: navigation, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

You must have seen lot of posts saying that robot keeps on rotating when it is near the goal but I have an opposite problem. In my case, when the robot reaches the goal within `xy_goal_tolerance`, it turns slowly to correct its orientation but then it stops outside the `yaw_goal_tolerance` at the goal. When I did `rostopic echo /cmd_vel`, the angular velocity (`angular.z`) is getting published (0.5 in my case) but the robot is not rotating. I am using wheel_encoders for odometry, amcl for localization and move_base for navigation with local planner as TrajectoryPlanner. I am not able to figure out what is causing such a behavior. Has anyone encountered such an issue before?

**Update**:  When I did rostopic pub -1 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.5]', robot did not rotate but when I changed 0.5 to 1, robot started to rotate. Then, I changed min_in_place_vel_theta = 1.0 in `base_local_planner_params.yaml` but still `angular.z` from `rostopic echo/cmd_vel` is 0.5 and the robot is not able to rotate and ends up in a wrong orientation at the goal. Any idea why is this happening? Do I need to change any other parameter?

base_local_planner_params.yaml

```
#For full documentation of the parameters in this file, and a list of all the
#parameters available for TrajectoryPlannerROS, please see
#http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  #Set the acceleration limits of the robot
  acc_lim_th: 2.5 
  acc_lim_x: 2.0
  acc_lim_y: 0

  #Set the velocity limits of the robot
  max_vel_x: 1.0
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_vel_theta: 1.0
  min_vel_theta: -1.0
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.5

  #The velocity the robot will command when trying to escape from a stuck situation
  escape_vel: -0.1
  
  #For this example, we'll use a holonomic robot
  holonomic_robot: false

  #Set the tolerance on achieving a goal
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

  #We'll configure how long and with what granularity we'll forward simulate trajectories
  sim_time: 1.5
  sim_granularity: 0.025
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.025
  vx_samples: 8
  vtheta_samples: 20

  #Parameters for scoring trajectories
  goal_distance_bias: 0.8
  path_distance_bias: 1.0
  gdist_scale: 0.8
  pdist_scale: 1.0
  occdist_scale: 0.01
  heading_lookahead: 0.325

  #We'll use the Dynamic Window Approach to control instead of Trajectory Rollout for this example
  dwa: false

  #How far the robot must travel before oscillation flags are reset
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05

  #Eat up the plan as the robot moves along it
  prune_plan: false

  # Global Frame id
  global_frame_id: odom_combined
```

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208693/wrong-robot-orientation-at-the-goal/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-05-06**:
If you run:
rostopic pub -1 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.5]'
does your robot move?  I had a robot that had a min_in_place_vel_theta of 0.6 before.

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-12**:
When I did that, robot did not able rotate but when I changed 0.5 to 1, robot rotated. Then, I changed min_in_place_vel_theta = 1.0, in this case also the robot did not rotate because angular.z in cmd_vel was still 0.5. Any idea why is this happening? Do I need to change some other parameter? Thanks

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-05-12**:
I would slowly increment the 0.5 on the rostopic pub command until the robot starts rotating.  Maybe in 0.05  increments (ie. 0.5, 0.55, ...). Record that value and use it for the min_in_place_vel_theta.   The max_vel_x  = 1.0 is a high value.  I would do a similar technic to determine the min_vel_x

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-05-12**:
and max_vel_x.  If you publish all zero it will stop your robot.

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-15**:
Ok..Thanks! One thing: when I change `min_in_place_vel_theta` to 1.0, and the robot is at the goal and wants to turn in place, base_local_planner still sends `angular.z` which is less than 1.0 (0.4,0.6) and the robot fails to correct its orientation.. Do you know why is this happening? TIA

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-05-19**:
I don't, your numbers look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please, try to increase the xy_goal_tolerance & yaw_goal_tolerance and start testing again.

Best regards,
Wagan Sarukhanov

---

Originally posted by [Wagan Sarukhanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/22367/wagan-sarukhanov/) with karma: 33 on 2015-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-12**:
I think 0.2 (20 cm and ~ 11 degrees) for each of them should be good

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe your robot is not performinng an "in place rotation"? Try to also change `min_vel_theta`.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-15**:
Thanks I will try it! One thing: when I change `min_in_place_vel_theta` to 1.0, and the robot is at the goal and wants to turn in place, base_local_planner still sends `angular.z` which is less than 1.0 (0.4,0.6) and the robot fails to correct its orientation.. Do you know why is this happening? TIA